# Is there an idiom that means "that something seems to be brewing"?

Tags: idiom-request

Idioms are hard to search for, especially if it cannot be put in a single word. This is one of those cases I believe, so are there idioms that allows you to say that something doesn't feel right, your sixth sense tells you that something bad may happen, or other similar things?

For example:

> I am a bit worried, there's ____.
>
> I don't like where this is going, I feel ____.

Comment: There are many possible answers here. Is this sort of list request on-tiopic?

Comment: Unless you can narrow down what you've considered and rejected (and why), this question is too broad. I could probably list about twenty phrases that have this meaning without spending much time on it. (As Han Solo said, *I've got a funny feeling about this.*)

Comment: The expression "something is brewing" is itself an idiom. It's literal meaning has to do with making drinks or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression, 'something's brewing' means that something is about to happen or something is being prepared.  The verb 'to brew' literally means to prepare beer and is also used when referring to making other drinks that require a long time to make and involve cooking, such as a witch's potion. When we  say 'something's brewing' it means it's gradually coming into existence,  like beer  being brewed. It doesn't by itself convey the sense that something's wrong or that what's brewing is bad.

The phrase, 'there's a storm brewing' can have the sense that something bad or disturbing is going to happen.

Some other idiomatic phrases that have similar meanings are

> something's rotten in Denmark.
>   that doesn't smell right.
>   this is going south
>   there's something fishy going on

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm a bit worried, there's something **shady**/**fishy** about this.
2. I don't like where this is going **I'm smelling a rat**.